# In Java how do I split a String by null char without using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have code of the form

```
 String[] splitValues = s.split("\\u0000");
```

that is called alot, when I did profiling I saw that each call was a regex (Pattern) to be compiled and run this was causing a significant performance impact.

I can easily compile the pattern just once but then running split still takes up significant cpu

I then looked at code for String,split() and it does optimizations if just passed a single char or backslash char but it not working for me because I specify null as `\u0000`, but I cant see how else I can do it,

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
        /* fastpath if the regex is a
         (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
            RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
         (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
            the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
         */
        char ch = 0;
        if (((regex.length() == 1 &&
             ".$|()[{^?*+\\".indexOf(ch = regex.charAt(0)) == -1) ||
             (regex.length() == 2 &&
              regex.charAt(0) == '\\' &&
              (((ch = regex.charAt(1))-'0')|('9'-ch)) < 0 &&
              ((ch-'a')|('z'-ch)) < 0 &&
              ((ch-'A')|('Z'-ch)) < 0)) &&
            (ch < Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE ||
             ch > Character.MAX_LOW_SURROGATE))
        {
```

**How can I split by null separator without need to use regular expression ?**

Comment: If you have a `\0` in the middle of your data, probably `String` is not the best container for your data.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the data is from ID3 metadata, and that uses \0 to sperate multiple strings within a String, so that is the starting point and cannot be changed.

Comment: I get it, but you probably should read those metadata as `byte[]`, separate on `\0` and then put the parts in strings. Reading binary data in `String`s usually doesn't end well.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca its not binary data, its text data please just address the specific question I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

```
String[] splitValues = s.split("\\u0000");
```

with

```
String[] splitValues = s.split("\0");
```

continues to work, but importantly allows `String.split()` to use its *fastpath* and so the split works without requiring the use of regular expressions.

What I am finding slightly confusing is why I had a `\\` originally because  doesn't that mean the \ is treated as a literal backslash and therefore the u0000 would not be treated as unicode char ?

Answer (score 1):

The "simple" way would be to precompile the regex:

```
static final Pattern NULL_SEPARATOR = Pattern.compile("\\u0000");
```

Then just do the same as on [the last line](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2367):

```
String[] parts = NULL_SEPARATOR.split(this, limit);
```

---

Or, you could add things to a `List` instead of building an array:

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length();) {
  int start = i;
  i = input.indexOf('\0', start);
  if (i < 0) i = input.length();

  parts.add(input.substring(start, i));

  if (i < input.length()) {
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Of course, this gives you a `List<String>`, rather than a `String[]`; this may or may not work for you. This has the convenience of growing the collection for you, but you can do that yourself with a `String[]` too.

Depending on [profiling], you might want to consider pre-sizing the list, for example by iterating the characters looking for `\0`s as a first pass.

Comment: okay  i could use the List idea, and iterating through the chars like will be quicker ?

Comment: Ive already done the precompile so that basiclaly haves the time taken, but still using the regex is significant.

Comment: You'll have to try it. Using `indexOf` is probably going to be quicker than manual iteration.

Comment: Just wondering would String[] splitValues = s.split("\0"); work and allow use of the String,split() fastpath avoiding use of regex ?

Comment: Yes, testing and profilng above it works without using rexex so a a very simple solution afterall

Answer (score -1):

There is an Open Source java library MgntUtils that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

So what I suggest is that you can write a simple code like this

```
public static final String DELIMITER = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString("\\u0000");
...
String[] splitValues = s.split(DELIMITER);
```

This will allow you to run `split()` method without regex as `DELIMITER` will hold the null symbol as a `String`.

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.8/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)